# Cannot print out correctly when "re.compile" in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

After insert the "re.compile" to row, cannot print out chinese character, thanks !

Compare output between table and rows:

output from table "title="添加置顶"

and

output from rows "title="\u6dfb\u52a0\u7f6e\u9876"

```
#coding:utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """"
<table align="center" bgcolor="#DDDDDD" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mytable" id="table_live" width="100%"><tbody>
<tr align="center" id="tr_0" style="background-color:#6BADDF;color:white">
<td bgcolor="#ff9933" height="20" width="2%">选</td>
<td style="cursor:pointer;" title="角球总比数/半场比分" width="6%">角/半</td></tr>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" id="tr1_1545801" index="1" odds="" style="height:18px;display:none">
<td><input class="inp" id="chk_1545801" type="checkbox"/></td>
<td><a href="javascript:addConcern(1,13);" title="添加置顶"><img src="image/unTop.png"/></a></td></tr>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', id="table_live")
rows = table.findAll("tr", {"id" : re.compile('tr1_\d{7}')})

print table
print rows
```

1)table can be print out chinese character
but 2)rows cannot print our chinese character

output from table

```
<table align="center" bgcolor="#DDDDDD" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mytable" id="table_live" width="100%"><tbody><tr align="center" id="tr_0" style="background-color:#6BADDF;color:white">
<td bgcolor="#ff9933" height="20" width="2%">选</td>
<td style="cursor:pointer;" title="角球总比数/半场比分" width="6%">角/半</td></tr>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" id="tr1_1545801" index="1" odds="" style="height:18px;display:none"><td><input class="inp" id="chk_1545801" type="checkbox"/></td>
<td><a href="javascript:addConcern(1,13);" title="添加置顶"><img src="image/unTop.png"/></a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

output from rows

```
[<tr align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" id="tr1_1545801" index="1" odds="" style="height:18px;display:none"><td><input class="inp" id="chk_1545801" type="checkbox"/></td>\n<td><a href="javascript:addConcern(1,13);" title="\u6dfb\u52a0\u7f6e\u9876"><img src="image/unTop.png"/></a></td></tr>]
```

Comment: for me both print out Chinese characters. Which versions are you using:

Comment: I'm using version 2.7.11+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rows` doesn't print out Chinese characters because it is a list and the way lists are printed by default is to show the safe representation of the strings they contain. For example, `\u6dfb` is used to safely represent the character 添 in situations where we might not be able to display unicode characters. We can force this string to be interpreted as unicode by putting 'u' in front of it.

```
print '\u6dfb'
# \u6dfb
print u'\u6dfb'
# 添
```

Anyway, in your example, if we print the individual rows we can see that they print fine, and it was only the fact we were printin gthem as a list that caused the problem:

```
#coding:utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """"
<table align="center" bgcolor="#DDDDDD" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mytable" id="table_live" width="100%"><tbody>
<tr align="center" id="tr_0" style="background-color:#6BADDF;color:white">
<td bgcolor="#ff9933" height="20" width="2%">选</td>
<td style="cursor:pointer;" title="角球总比数/半场比分" width="6%">角/半</td></tr>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" id="tr1_1545801" index="1" odds="" style="height:18px;display:none">
<td><input class="inp" id="chk_1545801" type="checkbox"/></td>
<td><a href="javascript:addConcern(1,13);" title="添加置顶"><img src="image/unTop.png"/></a></td></tr>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', id="table_live")
rows = table.findAll("tr", {"id" : re.compile('tr1_*\d')})

print rows
# [<tr align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" id="tr1_1545801" index="1" odds="" style="height:18px;display:none">\n<td><input class="inp" id="chk_1545801" type="checkbox"/></td>\n<td><a href="javascript:addConcern(1,13);" title="\u6dfb\u52a0\u7f6e\u9876"><img src="image/unTop.png"/></a></td></tr>]
for row in rows:
    print row
# <tr align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" id="tr1_1545801" index="1" odds="" style="height:18px;display:none">
# <td><input class="inp" id="chk_1545801" type="checkbox"/></td>
# <td><a href="javascript:addConcern(1,13);" title="添加置顶"><img src="image/unTop.png"/></a></td></tr>
```

For fun, we can make python print exactly what you want using repr (but remember the type of what's being printed here is a string).

```
import sys
# Convert the list into a string representation that displays chinese characters that we can print...
representation = repr([x.encode(sys.stdout.encoding) for x in rows]).decode('string-escape')
print representation
# ['<tr align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" id="tr1_1545801" index="1" odds="" style="height:18px;display:none">
# <td><input class="inp" id="chk_1545801" type="checkbox"/></td>
# <td><a href="javascript:addConcern(1,13);" title="添加置顶"><img src="image/unTop.png"/></a></td></tr>']
print(type(representation))
#<type 'str'>
```

For even more fun, try running your original code in Python 3 - You'll see exactly the output you wanted, because Python 3 handles unicode in a more intuitive way.